# Add meta information to dropped messages in NLog

Tags: .net, logging, metadata, nlog

We intend to introduce NLog in a C# application with multiple targets, including the common log file but also a target showing specific messages as popup (e.g. relevant warnings or errors).

Is there any possibility to add kind of a meta information when dropping the message to NLog, like a flag whether the messages is relevant for the user during execution apart from solely the log level?

In other words, there may be logs with level "**Warning**" which should be written in the log file, while others additionally should trigger opening a message box in the UI as well. The differentiation somehow needs to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to add context information:

- The name of the logger. Maybe have a special logger-instance for LogEvents that should be shown in messsage-box.
- The warning level of the LogEvent.
- LogEvent-Properties. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer
- Diagnostic Context: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer or https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NDLC-Layout-Renderer

This information can be used in the filtering logic in the logging-rules: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, after thinking about the possible solutions we decided to use the custom parameters of type object in the log method, which seems to be the most comfortable and easiest way to fulfill our needs!